# Highcharts - Heatmap [issue with xaxis, suggestion for improvements]

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap using highcharts.

It looks like as shown below
[image]

As you can see that on x-axis there is an empty section after the month March. How can i remove it so that the range October to March fits completely on x axis.

Secondly how can i improve the color scheme or make it appear nicer.

code for above heatmap

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    },

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        margin: [60, 10, 80, 50]
    },

    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Traffic',
        align: 'center',
        x: 40
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: yyy',
        align: 'center',
        x: 40
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        min: Date.UTC(2016, 9, 1),
        max: Date.UTC(2017, 4, 0),
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 5,
            y: 14,
            format: '{value:%B}' // long month
        },
        showLastLabel: false,
        tickLength: 16
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}:00'
        },
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24],
        tickWidth: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 23,
        reversed: true
    },

    colorAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0, '#3060cf'],
            [0.1, '#66aee2'],
            [0.2, '#8ec5ed'],
            [0.3, '#4ee8b4'],
            [0.4, '#7ee567'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [0.6, '#f2c05e'],
            [0.7, '#ed9549'],
            [0.8, '#ed7031'],
            [0.9, '#ed4d21'],
            [1, '#c4463a']
        ],
        min: 1000,
        max: 150000,
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        boostThreshold: 100,
        borderWidth: 0,
        nullColor: '#EFEFEF',
        colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: 'Hits<br/>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value}</b>'
        },
        turboThreshold: Number.MAX_VALUE // #3404, remove after 4.0.5 release
    }]

});
```

Comment: Set [xAxis.max](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max) to the last point's x value. You can change the color for the data in colorAxis options http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis, e.g. minColor, maxColor, stops.

Comment: max here is a date which is in year, month, date format. So if i make the date to be (2017, 3, 0) then months are repeated.

Comment: If you set xAxis.max to the x value which is held by one of the points which the right-most, the chart will not have any blank spaces.